# Cannot seem to load shapefiles using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal

I have been searching on GIS for a solution to this essentially I have a shapefile .shp on my desktop also where I am saving this py script. The .shp also has the associated files. But when I try this code snippet I found on here I get back "couldn't load shapefile":

```
import osgeo
import osgeo.ogr
try:
    shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open("world.shp")

    if shapefile: # checks to see if shapefile was successfully defined
        numLayers = shapefile.GetLayerCount()
    else: # if it's not successfully defined
        print "Couldn't load shapefile"
except: # Seems redundant, but if an exception is raised in the Open() call,
    # you get a message
    print "Exception raised during shapefile loading"

    # if you want to see the full stacktrace - like you are currently getting,
    # then you can add the following:
    raise
```

Any ideas on why this would not work? I am using spyder and have gdal installed onto anaconda.

Comment: Have you try to load the .shp in a gis software like qgis? Maybe is corrupted

Comment: Call [`gdal.UseExceptions()`](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions) near the top of your script.  Get rid of the `try:` `except:` for testing, they just hide the actual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine. I ran it without errors.

You could modify it a bit so it is obvious if it works:

```
if shapefile: # checks to see if shapefile was successfully defined
    numLayers = shapefile.GetLayerCount()
    print(numLayers)
```

Make sure you are running it in the same folder as world.shp.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that it still gives me "cannot open shapefile". I have that file that says world.shp on my desktop. I don't know why it won't open. I opened world.shp on QGIS and it came up just fine. Am not sure but maybe it has to do with where python is being executed/saved and where this world.sph file is (desktop). Although the py script is also saved on my desktop. Also this is being used through Spyder python 2.7.

Comment: Where does my shape file have to be in order for it to open?

Comment: It doesn't matter where your file is if you specify the full path to it. Usually though, next to your .py file should work.

Comment: Yeah if you don't specify a full path it needs to be where you run the script from.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, It was solved when I put all other files (.dbf, .prj etc.) in the same directory as the shape file. Apparently all of these are required.